# filtering results in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an ElasticSearch query that is coming up as being malformed, just not sure what it is I am doing wrong (no doubt somethign very obvious!)

the query looks like this:

```
{ "query":
{ "filtered":
    { "query":
        { "field":
            { "product":"prodA or prodB" 
            } 
        }, 
        "filter":
            { 
                "userid":"username" 
            } 
    } 
}, 
"size":10, "from":0 
}
```

If I leave out the filter section, the query works just fine, so It must be something to do with the way I am using the filter option.

```
{ "query":
{ "filtered":
    { "query":
        { "field":
            { "product":"prodA or prodB" 
            } 
        }

    } 
}, 
"size":10, "from":0 
}
```

How do I need to format this query to make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify what kind of filter you want to use, like you do with the query when you choose the filtered one. [Term filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/term-filter.html)?

```
{ 
    "query": { 
        "filtered": { 
            "query": { 
                "field":{ 
                    "product":"prodA or prodB" 
                } 
            }, 
            "filter": {
                "term" : { 
                    "userid":"username" 
                }                           
            } 
        } 
    }, 
    "size":10, 
    "from":0 
}
```